# Deserialization of JSON object with List<> using DataContractJsonSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to deserialize a JSON object that contains a single member; a string array:

```
{"errores":[{"errorCode":"campo1","errorMessage":"Errorenelcampo1"},{"errorCode":"campo2","errorMessage":"Errorenelcampo2"},{"errorCode":"campo3","errorMessage":"Errorenelcampo3"},{"errorCode":"campo4","errorMessage":"Errorenelcampo4"}]}"
```

This is the class that I'm trying to deserialize into:

```
[DataContract]
internal class rptaNo
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Errors> errores { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    protected internal struct Errors
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the method that I try to deserialize:

```
public T Deserialise<T>(string json)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        T result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
        return result;
    }
}
```

But when I check, all fields of the sub list are blank, for example

```
MessageBox.Show(deserializedRpta2.errores[0].descripcion);
```

I guess there must be something I'm missing = (

Comment: Have you try `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialization of JSON object by using DataContractJsonSerializer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409655/deserialization-of-json-object-by-using-datacontractjsonserializer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

your model needs to have properties that match the names of JSON objects:

```
[DataContract]
protected internal struct Errors
{
    [DataMember]
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the [Name property of DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name.aspx). It makes "harmless" refactors less-likely to break existing contracts.

Comment: @stvn03 If an answer works out for you, you typically accept it so future visitors can quickly see that it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public string errorCode
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string errorMessage
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    string json = @"[{""errorCode"":""code1"",""errorMessage"":""value1""}, {""errorCode"":""code2"",""errorMessage"":""value2""}, {""errorCode"":""code3"",""errorMessage"":""value3""}] ";
    JavaScriptSerializer deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List items = deserializer.Deserialize>(json);

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.errorCode + ":" + item.errorMessage);
    }
```